# Codeigniter Database Query Caching No Updating With New Data Or Removed Data

Tags: codeigniter

When I add new category to my database it insert fine. But the [Codeigniter Database Query Cache](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html) does not update when add or remove

> **Question:** Once I add a new category or delete a category how to make sure the codeigniter database cache query gets updated correct

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'community',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => TRUE,
    'cachedir' => APPPATH . 'cache/database/',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Forum Model

```
public function getcategories() {
    $this->db->cache_on(); // Cache On

    $query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->order_by('name', 'asc')
            ->from('forum')
            ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

public function add() {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->trans_strict(FALSE);

    $insert = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
        'pid' => $this->input->post('pid')
    );

    $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'forum', $insert);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return TRUE;
    }
}

public function categories_for_deletion($fid) {
    $this->db->where('fid', $fid);
    $this->db->or_where('pid', $fid);

    $query = $this->db->delete('forum');

    $this->db->cache_delete('admin', 'category');
    if ($query) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Category extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('forum');
        $this->load->model('admin/forum/forum_model');
    }

    public function add() {     
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $this->forum_model->add();

            redirect('admin/category');

        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $data['categories'] = $this->forum->generate_select();

        $this->load->view('template/forums/category_add_view', $data);
    }

    public function edit($fid) {        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('template/forums/category_edit_view', $data);
    }

    public function delete($fid) {
        $delete = $this->forum_model->categories_for_deletion($fid);

        if ($delete == TRUE) {
            redirect('admin/category');
        }


        $this->index();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['categories'] = '';

        if ($this->forum_model->getcategories()) {
            $data['categories'] = $this->forum->set_categories_list($this->forum_model->getcategories());
        }

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['navbar'] = Modules::run('admin/common/navbar/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

        $this->load->view('template/forums/category_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working like query cache (schema cache) or only data cache?

Comment: I read the documentation carefully and comes to know that cache files will not updated/expires. You need to do it explicitly. I tried the same thing and it happened with me too. So what I did, I introduce a cron job to delete the cache files manually after interval. I know running cron job is not good idea, but I did not have any other choice for that time.

Comment: @kishor10d Thanks for the info will not be using codeigniter database query cache any more,

Answer (score 1):

As [kishor10d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494790/kishor10d) said, the queries will neither update, nor expire automatically or after any duration. You'll have to do it manually, but it doesn't require a cron job or anything. Codeigniter has a method for it.

After every update, you have to do a

```
$this->db->cache_delete('controller', 'method');
```

If you don't pass any parameters, it uses current URI to delete associated cache. When your query completes, the cache will be added again giving an effect of an update.

Reference: [$this->db->cache_delete() on CodeIgniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html#this-db-cache-delete)